# Setting multiple properties of multiple controls

Tags: matlab, set

This is a very simple question, but after reading the documentation I can't assign the position property to a group of axes controls. I actually want to set 2 properties to a group of 11 axes controls, specifically the position and the parent properties. This is the code I'm using:

```
set(h.AXES_ALL(1:11),'parent',h.fig,{'position'},{ ...
    [30/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]  ...
    [300/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
    [570/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
    [840/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
    [1110/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]...
    [30/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]  ...
    [300/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
    [570/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
    [840/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
    [1110/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]...
    [570/win_pos(3) 20/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]    })
```

Where `win_pos` is a vector corresponding to the position of the window. The error MATLAB is giving is:

> Size mismatch in Param Cell / Value Cell pair

So, is it possible to change these 2 properties to a large group of controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign different values of a single property to multiple objects, your cell array of values needs to be a *column*, not a row (see [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/set.html)). So: add `.'` after your last `}`:

```
set(h.AXES_ALL(1:11),'parent',h.fig,{'position'},{[30/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]  ...
                                       [300/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
                                       [570/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
                                       [840/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
                                       [1110/win_pos(3) 460/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]...
                                       [30/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]  ...
                                       [300/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
                                       [570/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
                                       [840/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)] ...
                                       [1110/win_pos(3) 240/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]...
                                       [570/win_pos(3) 20/win_pos(4) 240/win_pos(3) 190/win_pos(4)]    }.')
```

Comment: Now it's not working. All the plots remain in the position of the last plot. I'm following your code and I don't understand where the problem is. Any suggestion?

Comment: But did it work initially? What have you changed since it was working?